# Using React Native to Speak to AWS - Get item: key is federatedInfo with options undefined error

Tags: database, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I followed this guide,

https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/quick_start

This uses react native to speak to a amazon cloud database,

Everything goes fine untill I run the application on my emulator and I get this output:

```
11:09:13: Starting Android...

 › Press a to open Android device or emulator.
 › Press q to display QR code.
 › Press r to restart packager, or R to restart packager and clear cache.
 › Press d to toggle development mode. (current mode: development)

11:09:44: Finished building JavaScript bundle in 28795ms
11:09:47: Get item: key is federatedInfo with options undefined
11:09:47: Get item: key is federatedInfo with options undefined
11:09:47: Running app on HUAWEI MLA-AL10 in development mode

11:09:47: Get item: key is federatedInfo with options undefined
11:09:47: Get item: key is federatedInfo with options undefined
11:09:52: Get item: key is AWSAnalytics_REALLYLONGSTRING with options undefined
```

I followed the guide perfectly but it still doesn't work, I followed the guide of installing Yarn and it looked happy but still gave this error at the end.

Is this because of my setup or the AWS permissions side?

Thank you for any help :)

[image: Screenshot]

## UPDATE:

Apparently these are not errors they are more like warning information, I spoke to the people over at Amazon and they said something about them being about the fact that i'm trying to access the database directly and not through a sign in api. Not really sure if I understood them correctly but they were pretty chilled about it.

If anyone has anymore information about it or can clarify further I will select that as the correct answer so the question can close.

Comment: What is the folder structure of your project?

Comment: Hi, I've add a image to the bottom of the question. Cheers

Comment: @PaulMcloughlin Can file structure be a issue?

Comment: What is your version of yarn?

Comment: @PaulMcloughlin I don't even think I have it installed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48953078/aws-amplify-api-get-federateinfo-with-options-undefined-error Have a look here

Comment: Yeah I had found this before but couldn't link to me, I'm not setting it manually

Comment: Any luck finding an answer to this?

Comment: I found out an answer to one of your other problems, in your aws-exports.js file add Analytics: {
    disabled: true
  }, this will get rid of that analytics error at least.

Comment: I haven't yet @JosephAstrahan but apparently there not errors, this is coming from the guys over at amazon

Comment: That is very good to know!

Comment: @JosephAstrahan I've updated the questions but the short story is that you shouldn't worry about them, the guys over at amazon we're chilled about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get item: key is federatedInfo with options undefined error

Is apparently not a error message and is more like a warning message.

It has to do with the way that I'm accessing the information from my react native app.

I spoke to the AWS guys and they said not to take notice of them, So that's what I'll do.

Answer (score 0):

Install Yarn, then look have a look [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/wiki/Local-Development) it mentions something about needing yarn in order to develop locally.

Comment: Yes, yarn has a window installer.

Comment: This didn't solve the issue but I believed helped. Everything went through until the end I've updated the question.

Comment: I've now change the question.